# Compare values in array and remove items that are not the same in Ruby/Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter

I have an array of items/values sent by my form.
I want to compare the values for each item, and remove/match the items only if the values are not the same. I added some comments in code to help.

```
    temp_array = []
    # remove/match duplicate drinks with different values
    params[:drinks].values.each do |v| 
                    
        # get drink id
        drink_id = v[:id]   
                    
        # store values in temp_array
        temp_array << v
                    
        # if the values below are NOT the same for the SAME drink_id
        # store them in a new array to perform task on them
        v[:optimized_nickname], v[:optimized_country_id], v[:optimized_region_id]
        # ...
        # compare values to values set in temp_array for same drink_id
                    
    end
```

The goal is to mark all drinks with different values (at least 1 different value) for same drink/drink_id with a `status=0`.

**I need/want to check the different values, not use all values sent by the form.**

I'm quite sure a simple solution exists with .map or .filter but I have difficulties to use them.
Thanks in advance,

EDIT: as requested, an example with what I want:

```
# the form sends this, first and third drinks have same id wbut different values
"drinks"=>{
"season_id_a9840059-cc91-47aa-9098-4bf8a45655e7"=>{"id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"La Dame", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "optimized_region_id"=>"2"}, 
"season_id_8ee93dc5-abd3-4cdd-ad20-29fcf1168a66"=>{"id"=>"de034565-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"La Dame", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "optimized_region_id"=>"2"}, 
"season_id_f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32"=>{"id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"L'homme", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "optimized_region_id"=>"2"}, 
}

# I want to keep the second drink
# drinks OK => STATUS 1
"drinks_OK"=>{
"season_id_8ee93dc5-abd3-4cdd-ad20-29fcf1168a66"=>{"id"=>"de034565-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"La Dame", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "optimized_region_id"=>"2"}, 
}

# I want to remove/edit the first and third with an update
# drinks KO => STATUS 0
"drinks_KO"=>{
"season_id_a9840059-cc91-47aa-9098-4bf8a45655e7"=>{"id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"La Dame", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "optimized_region_id"=>"2"}, 
"season_id_f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32"=>{"id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"L'homme", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "optimized_region_id"=>"2"}, 
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of input and expected output please?

Comment: I think you could try to experiment with `params[:drinks].values.group_by {|v| v[:id]}.transform_values(&:uniq)`

Comment: BroiSatse, I added an example with values.

Comment: And I want to check the values to compare, not use all values. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject):

```
params[drinks].values.reject {|i| i == v[:id]}
```

Will return an array with values that are not equal to `v[:id]`

Comment: mejiaro, I think, it's not what I want to do. I want to reject only if at least one value is not the same for the same drink, this means I need to compare `v[:optimized_nickname], v[:optimized_country_id]`...etc

Comment: If the return value from `reject` is empty then that means are your values are the same. if it isn't empty then you have the values that are different and can do with them whatever you need.